# Identification - What kind of animal leaves these tracks?

Tags: species-identification

I live in the suburbs of Washington DC where it recently snowed. I was admiring all of the tracks left behind by wildlife of all kinds when I came across these prints, that I was unable to recognize from charts of common animals prints online.

[image: animal print 1]

[image: animal print 3]

[image: animal print 4]

What is unique about them, is that each print, has 3 points, and there is only one straight line of prints, about 2-3 feet apart, where as I would imagine a deer, or other 4 legged animal would leave staggered footprints. We have a lot of deer in these parts but these dont seem to match deer print patterns I've seen online.

Each print is about 5 inches by 4 inches at their widest/longest points (they are longer then they are wider).

Note, the snow has melted somewhat since they were initially made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only candidate I could imagine is [hare](https://www.google.com/search?q=hare%20footprints).
Sometimes it leaves a single track from its fore-limbs (from a theoretical point of view, I'd say it happens when the snow is relatively deep.)

Comment: I'd say hare too - seen them leaving tracks here!

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Upon closer inspection and watching some videos on youtube on how hares move, it seems that the "dot" may be its front paws close together and the 2 longer lines are its hind legs. Seeing them walk its common for them to cross their hind legs in front of their front paws creating this pattern.

Comment: O, I wrote "hind-limbs" - now corrected.

Comment: @n00b I had the same confusion when I first encountered these tracks, it wasn't until I found some very fresh ones where I could even see the pads of the paws that I worked out what it was.